# Can't burninate from the get-go due to title problems

Tags: feature-request, meta, title

The ban on pseudo-tagging in titles, which make sense for Stack Overflow, means that on Meta, you can't start a title with a tag.

For example, you can't write "[bidirectional] is going in two directions" as a Meta SO title.

Feature request: allow pseudo-tags anywhere in a title on Meta, including at the start of a title.

Comment: Well, one can fake it. ;-)

Comment: Hey, you can't have it both ways...;)

Comment: Alternative title: `Should [bidirectional] come or go?`

Comment: So what are your proposing as a feature?  That you can start a title with a tag?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf On meta, yes.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Question edited accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

A zero-width space at the beginning does the trick.