# Why do we have this tag[questionmark]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Uh, why is there a [questionmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/questionmark) tag?

117 questions. [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372456/html-pages-show-%EF%BF%BD-questions-marks-instead-of-japan-character-in-server) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988552/xmlpullparser-black-diamond-question-marks-with-certain-characters) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959751/console-isnt-showing-pretty-characters-in-shell) Unicode character: �. [An occasional question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997529/ruby-syntax-what-is-the-difference-between-and-if-else) about some syntax involving `?` (possibly valid? but this is like having a tag for `or`). Others...well, as far as I can tell, [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308091/what-is-the-worst-case-time-analysis-for-the-following-loop) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173820/is-there-a-way-to-store-multiple-values-to-an-int-variable-in-java) are tagged this simply because they are questions.

It has no wiki summary, I can't think of a reasonable use for this tag, so...[questionmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/questionmark)? We should probably get rid of it. Permanently. I don't think it should become the synonym of anything because it seems to be used for a bunch of different topics that have nothing to do with each other and will continue being a very confused tag containing querystrings and ternary expressions until allowed to die a peaceful death.

So, uh, canhaz flamez?

1. The ones about � should possibly be retagged <strike>unicode</strike> [character-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding).
2. `?` for [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) or [javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) or any other language that uses a `?` in their syntax should probably just lose the [questionmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/questionmark) tag.
3. Any question bearing the [questionmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/questionmark) tag for no good reason should lose it.
4. Questions about [query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500472/how-do-i-match-the-question-mark-character-in-a-django-url/5500547#5500547) should probably be retagged [query-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-string).

(**As a side note**: there are three tags for query strings: [query-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-string), [request.querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/request.querystring), and [querystringparameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/querystringparameter). As far as I know, those three are the exact same thing. [query-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-string) is the largest one and the only one with a tag wiki, so that's why I think query string questions should be retagged [query-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-string))

**Edited**: Thanks, everyone! Wow, that was fast.

Comment: Andrew invalidated your example by removing the tag... ;) I'm also curious about this one. Migrated from twitter, perhaps?

Comment: oh, there are plenty more examples :P

Comment: Add [ [tag:conditional-operator] ] for the ternary-operator (`a ? b : c`) or the elvis operator (`a ?: c`).

Comment: On lighter note :-), we can create tag[questionmark] here on meta and use in this question as it has lot of ? in this post.

Comment: � is not limited to unicode. I would rather use [tag:character-encoding].

Comment: Facepalm: [[tag:colon]]

Comment: Not fair, you get to have a pseudo-tag at the end of the question, but [I can't have one at the start](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299625/cant-burninate-from-the-get-go-due-to-title-problems)!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Done, questionmark is nuked.

Comment: Well, there's a migration stub to meta still. That will be gone in its own good time.

Comment: @Deduplicator [30 days](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292227) seems like a long time.

Comment: @ArtjomB.: As I said, its *own* good time, not ours.

Comment: Still there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/questionmark - But, the question which is shown in this list doesn't actually have the tag. What's going on with that?

Comment: @Rob Clicking the link redirects you to the migrated copy on meta, and tags aren't migrated. The [original question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577339/ignored-questions-on-stackoverflow?noredirect=1) still exists as a stub, and has the tag.

Answer (score 9):

**1**. and **3**.: yes, definitely.

**2**: @ArtjomB.'s suggestion

> Add [conditional-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-operator) for the ternary-operator `(a ? b : c)` or
>   the elvis operator `(a ?: c)`.

would not destroy information. (Maybe even make this a synonym)

**4**: ? (aka: what do the experts say?) ;-)

#### Elvis operator

Concerning the [originally Groovy-based elvis operator](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-July/002089.html), it

> is a shortcut for the ternary `if` operator when the `true` case
>   should yield the value of the conditional.

This does not necessarily return `true`, as

> `a ?: b`  only makes sense in Groovy because `a` can be of any
>   arbitrary type - and is not restricted to be a boolean expression. The
>   boolean value inside the conditional is calculated by the rules of the
>   "Groovy truth", where   objects can be casted to boolean such that
>   e.g. null objects are treated as `false`   just like empty Strings,
>   Maps, and Lists. Therefore, an Elvis expression does not necessarily
>   return a boolean   in Groovy but can be of any runtime type allowing
>   constructions like
>
> ```
> String s = a ?: "n/a"
> ```
>
> to set a reference to a default value if no proper value is available.
>   The same use comes handy in method calls like
>
> ```
> myMethod( a ?: "n/a" )
> ```

Comment: Elvis operator ... rofl

Comment: One learns something new on meta on each day. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator#.3F:_operator

Comment: @Jay: indeed, and comments sometime drive us to find out more (see the updated answer for a history doc)