# ​[fetch] the burninator! (1761)

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The tag wiki for [fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fetch), emphasis mine, seems pretty ambiguous to me.  Should it be burninated?

> fetch is a keyword in many programming languages which is usually used as part of an instruction to retrieve data
>
> **fetch is used in many contexts**, include source control, database querying, and cache control.

Comment: For anyone wondering, there is a zero-width space at the beginning of the title, evading the tag-prefix filter. Honestly, IMO users above a certain rep threshold should have a "I'm trying to do something clever here" button.

Comment: You may want to add a tag link (`[tag:fetch]`) in the question body.  Makes it easier to make suggestions about whether to burn it, or not. Side note: nice title.

Comment: A quick glance at the first page of results show a lot of abuse. However, in [this one about Git fetch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32902912/2564301) it seems entirely appropriate.

Comment: @Jongware I don't think so: the tag is still completely ambiguous.

Comment: I mean that the tag itself is [the Git command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch). Although I presume one can rename that one to `git-fetch`. (5 seconds later) Which exists, and is used correctly a whopping 6 times out of 50 on [the first page of a relevant search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+is%3Aq). So the other 44, plus the remainders in the other pages' 3,784, need renaming. (Sigh.)

Comment: I would say no to burnination. `[fetch]` by itself is bad, but in conjunction with other tags serves a purpose, for instance `git`, `ftp`, anything regarding the computer-architectural instruction fetch stage on any machine, ...

Comment: But no-one is an expert in fetch. No-one is looking for questions related to fetching. Some people are looking for questions about git fetch or fetch in related to ftp, but nobody is looking for fetch.

Comment: @Gaelan http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299625/cant-burninate-from-the-get-go-due-to-title-problems

Comment: A lot of the ones tagged with [tag:javascript] should have the [tag:fetch-api] tag instead.

Comment: Fetch must be stopped: 
https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/e1/a4/79/e1a4793d3fe6be37e580aa85ab994c16.jpg

Comment: Funny thing is, the wiki doesn't mention the most fundamental case of fetch, an [instruction fetch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_cycle) in a computer.